# Broadcasting RSS feed to another site through javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, rss

My boss came to me today and requested that I develop a snippet of code that we can share with some of our clients, which will display latest posts from an RSS feed. The idea is they will be able to paste the snippet on their site, and it will display the latest postings from out site.

Is this a common practice, and if so, how is it done? Through JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) to parse the RSS feed which I included in the snippet.